# Attach column names to elements with Spark and Scala using FlatMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatmap

For a given table like

```
+--+--+
| A| B|
+--+--+
|aa|bb|
|cc|dd|
+--+--+
```

I want to get a dataframe like:

```
+---+---+
|._1|._2|
+---+---+
|aa | A |
|bb | B |
|cc | A |
|dd | B |
+---+---+
```

using Apache Spark and Scala. So basically I want tuples that have the original values at index 0 and the column name at index 1. This should work for any arbitrary schema. That means that the amount of columns is not known beforehands and as far as I understand I therefore cannot cast to datasets. 
This is how I tried to solve it:

```
val df = spark.read
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("sep",";")
          .csv(path + "/tpch_nation.csv")
val cells = df.flatMap(tuple => {
          tuple.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]].zip(df.columns.toList)
        })
cells.show()
```

However, this produces an `java.lang.NullPointerException` inside the flatMap function. I am quite puzzled which object points to Null, and how I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `df` in the closure. Use columns separately

```
val columns = df.columns 

val cells = df.flatMap(row => {
  row.toSeq.map(_.toString).zip(columns)
})
```

or don't use at all:

```
val cells = df.flatMap(row => {
  row.toSeq.map(_.toString).zip(row.schema.fieldNames)
})
```

Also:

- [Transpose column to row with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37864222/8371915)
- [unpivot in spark-sql/pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42465568/8371915)
- [Spark DataFrame column names not passed to slave nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34456618/8371915)